# Warnings while creating a new project

Tags: android-studio

I'm facing an issue with Android Studio. When I create a new project by default the project doesn't go in the AndroidStudioProject Folder.

If I try to move the project into the AndroidStudioProjects folder, while creating the project I become a lot of warnings: The following file could not be created since it already exists: gradle-wrapper.jar The following file could not be created since it already exists: gradle-wrapper.properties If you proceed the resulting project may not compile or not work as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no default folder for saving new projects, there is only `Last project` location saved in your computer. So every project will be stored where last project was saved. (*Unless you change location*).

So, If you want to change the default location (which is technically the *Last location*), then you might wanted to change the location while creating a new project, and then all the succeeding projects will be saved in previously mentioned location.

Now this is what you have to do: Create a new project, point the project location to `AndroidStudioProjects` folder. Now, `Android Studio` will store every new project in that location.

Once that's done, then import all of your projects (*which are outside that folder*) in that folder by `import an existing project`.